# NativeScript roadmap: Desktop support no longer on the cards?

Tags: nativescript, desktop

I notice that desktop support isn't mentioned in NativeScript's future roadmap any more.

Has this been dropped for good, or is it still on the cards?

If it is still on the cards, for when is it planned?

Answer (score 2):

### NativeScript under Progress ownership

While NativeScript was owned by Progress, desktop support was never a priority; developer surveys did not show strong enough demand for it, and the NativeScript Core team were stretched too thinly to tackle it as a curiosity.

Of interest, before the death of Windows Phone, NativeScript did get very far on implementing a Universal Windows Platform runtime for NativeScript: https://github.com/NativeScript/windows-runtime

The NativeScript iOS runtime (https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime for JSC, https://github.com/NativeScript/ns-v8ios-runtime for V8) is also close to delivering Catalyst support, although it's essentially undocumented for now.

I spoke with the NativeScript iOS runtime team and they said it would be pretty trivial to generate JS bindings to macOS (AppKit/Cocoa), too – though one would still have to implement all the UI components as AppKit ones, so it would only be the start of the journey.

### Unofficial support

Kamen Bundev (on the Progress/Telerik NativeScript team) has been building a Qt-based desktop implementation of NativeScript as a hobby project for a long time:

https://github.com/bundyo/nativescript-platform-desktop

It has access to Node.js's APIs rather than, say, the Obj-C runtime on macOS, however.

### NativeScript under nStudio ownership

NativeScript was recently handed over to nStudio, who may have a different stance. This question did in fact receive an official answer recently on Twitter:

> [image: NativeScript say they expect by this summer to have reached a decision on whether to add desktop support to the roadmap.]

They have also expressed love for the idea of creating Windows 10 apps with it (the tweet links to this issue, https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8643):

> [image: NativeScript officially love Windows 10]

### My personal speculation

*Note that I do not work for nStudio, and the dust is still settling after the NativeScript handover, so everything from here is just speculation:*

So I think there's no question that the passion is there – the real question is whether they have the resources to back it. I personally think that there won't be any movement on it anytime soon, as nStudio need at least a few months just to get used to driving the NativeScript ecosystem and sorting out the long-standing open-source frictions. I think that they'd absolutely welcome a community-driven effort on this, of course. I imagine that by 2021 they'll feel more ready to take on projects of that scale.